# How to join two vectors with a large matrix into a data frame?

Tags: r

I've got two vectors int [1:100] and a large matrix [1:100, 1:316387] and I'm trying to merge them into a data frame.

```
years <- sample(1:10, 100, replace = T)
storms <- sample(1:10, 100, replace = T)
wind_speeds <- matrix(ncol = 316387, nrow = 100, 
                     data = sample(0:250, 31638700, replace = T))

wind_speeds_as_list <-  split(wind_speeds, 
                              rep(1:nrow(wind_speeds), 
                              each = ncol(wind_speeds)))

df <- data.frame(year=years, storm=storms, wind_speed_vector=t(wind_speeds_as_list))
```

I have tried to create a list with wind_speed but that doesn't get me what I'm after.

What I'm trying to do is combine this so that when I do a str of df I get:
100 obs. of 3 variables so that when I reference df$wind_speeds I'd get a list of 100 vectors each with 316387 entries.

Comment: Fixed it; thank you for noticing that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need a `list` column, we can wrap it with `I`

```
df <- data.frame(year=years, storm=storms, wind_speeds=I(wind_speeds_as_list)))
dim(df)
#[1] 100   3
length(df$wind_speeds)
#[1] 100
is.list(df$wind_speeds)
#[1] TRUE
sum(lengths(df$wind_speeds))
#[1] 31638700
```

Comment: Thank you for taking a look.  I'm trying to avoid having that many columns and am trying to make it 100 x 3 so that the third item in the data frame is itself a list or vector containing the 316387 items for any given year and storm.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick.  I had been struggling with that for a good bit.  Do you know if it is possible to accomplish the same thing but have df$wind_speeds as a vector?  I went down the list path because I thought that was the only way it would work.

Comment: @ChrisTownsend Then the column length will be different compared to the other columns.  One option is a `list` which can hold different lengths `lst <- list(years, storms, wind_speeds = unlist(wind_speeds_as_list))`

Comment: Thank you so much @akrun  Your posted example answers the question and works.  My extended use case is for subsequent processing with Apache Spark and R - when I try to create a SparkR data frame out of the local data frame it doesn't like the call to I and complains about the call to AsIs related to the I (inhibit conversion of objects).  That is a different problem though; thank you again.

Comment: @ChrisTownsend  I don't have SparkR to test it.  Can you post that as a new question.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  Your answer is the correct one for the question.  I ended up using melt and set my year and storm fields to the id.vars and this creates a much larger data frame but one that SparkR should be able to handle - it is ~ 650MB in R Studio and mushrooms out to exceed my available memory using SparkR - definitely another question.  Thank you again @akrun